# When is the product of a function with a positive linear one convex?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Let $f: Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a non-constant function and $g: \mathbb{R}^m_+ \times Y  \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows:
$$g(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) =  \mathbf{x}^T f(\mathbf{y})$$

I am looking for conditions on $f$ and $Y$ under which $g$ is guaranteed to be convex in $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ over the set $\mathbb{R}^m_+ \times Y$.

I have made attempts at proving that this function can never be convex but failed. I have  also failed at finding an example of an $f$ for which $g$ is convex. Any clues?

Comment: Trivial, but any constant $f$ will suffice as an example.

Comment: Ok, yes good point, have to precise that I am looking for non-constant functions.

Comment: Just looking at the case where $m=n=1$ and $f$ is $C^2$ it would seem that $f$ needs to be constant for this to be convex.